# Как реализовать игру "поиск предмета" в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Смысл в том, что на экране размещено много изображений( пусть это будут векторные силуэты в количестве 100-200 штук). Высвечивается название и если пользователь кликает на силуэт соответствующий этому названию, то высвечивается новое название, иначе игра заканчивается. Вопрос в том, как и где проще и лучше разместить столько элементов и как соотнести svg изображения с их названиями?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос несколько не практичный в нашем мире, но если вам нужно, возможно, их стоит поместить в grid layout, [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php) парень приводить отличный пример.